# Designing a bot to find location of objects in a field

Tags: artificial-intelligence, project

This is a part of my AI project. I have to implement a bot, which occupies a square, in a field of LXW squares. If a square in the field is empty, it has value 0, if it is occupied by an object, its value is 1. A continuous set of squares with value 1 is called an object.

I have to figure out the identity and location of all objects in the field

I have the following info :

sense() : this function returns occupancy status of my neighbouring 8 squares
move(x) : allows me to move to a neighbouring square in x direction
getId(x) : gives me id of object in x direction wrt me, and if there is no object, returns -1

However, whenever I call a sense or getID function, the object can move to a different position with a small probability

I was thinking of using BFS to traverse the grid. Or would it be better to keep a list of already traversed positions and move randomly?
What are some of the AI techniques that I could use to solve this problem? How about some planning techniques?

Comment: What happens if you run into an object blindly? How far away is "a different position"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the problem description! Deterministic approaches probably won't work, as there is some randomness involved. Also you might have to revisit some locations as new pathes may open due to object movement.

Therefore enhancing random movement is a good start. For example you could assign timestamps to each visited cell and make it more likely to visit unvisited/older cells. That is similar to the pheromones in Ant Colony Optimization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization only with a single ant.

Another approach might be to select random target cells (far away) and trying to get there. You will probably encounter objects along the way. Use naive pathfinding around those objects and if that doesn't work, just pick another target.

**Update**:

An abstract but powerful way to create a somewhat clever AI is to first think about rigid facts/properties/annotations that you can assign to your model (like visited locations, timestamps, a priori knowledge, etc.). Then create a set of simple actions that the AI can use. You might also want to create more complex actions on top of them.

Afterwards it all comes down to having the AI-controlled agents choose an appropriate action given the current facts in a non-deterministic way. That is: Assign scores to those possible actions and do a roulette wheel selection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection or something similar to determine the next action.

Comment: Thanks! Can you mention about some of the non-deterministic approaches that could be used, aside from timestamps?

Comment: @Karan: It depends how you mix deterministic and non-deterministic parts in an algorithm. Timestamps are of course deterministic, but if it is "more likely" to visit new cells, then you got your non-determinism. I'll update my answer for an example.

Comment: Could you shed some light on how I should handle objects that have only 1 space in between them? I guess getID() will solve the problem (so that I know which object a filled block belongs to), but this might cause the object to move. Any workaround?

Comment: @Karan: No, that's a difficult problem. The only way to know the exact size of small objects is when they are unable to move due to border or neighboring constraints. Or to be lucky...